# How much "repeated deletion of answered questions" will cause a ban?

Tags: support, questions, deleted-questions, post-ban, vote-to-delete

I have a question with -6 negative votes and just when I was about to deleted my question, the only answer got +1.

Now I can't delete my question and already had a vote for delete.

But if I try to vote for delete myself got this message.

[image]

I got one question delete by comunity long time ago. Maybe a year.

So if my question is comunity vote for delete then that go against me too?

And if I vote for delete how often Repeated deletion cause the ask ban.

Comment: The ban you are talking about rarely hits people with a significant amount of rep.

Comment: See [What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account”?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583) for all public information on post bans.

Comment: Not that you are anywhere near a post ban, not with 210 questions, 36.7k rep and the Curious and Inquisitive badges...

Comment: @MartijnPieters Looks like I understand the message wrong. After some thinking seem that message is if I try to delete someone else question. Because I cant vote for delete in my own question. In that case mean I can be ban for repeatdly delete others people questions with negative votes and one upvote answer.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: No, I got your message just fine, yes you can *vote* to delete other peoples posts. Doesn't mean you'll succeed or that they'll be question-banned just because you voted to delete. If they have a *track record* of asking many bad questions that end up deleted, then they will indeed get question-banned. But your delete votes on their posts are then just playing a very small part and you are doing your job if you are helping keep the site clean.

Comment: But that isnt what the text said.  `Repeated deletion of answered questions can result in your account being blocked from asking.` That said my account can be ban for deletion. But I cant delete my questions so mean I can get banned for vote for delete others questions

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: Does that message appear when you try to delete *other* people's answered questions? Context *matters*.

Comment: @NicolBolas Dont know. Appear when try to delete my own answer.But is weird they warned you about the risk of delete your question but then said you cant delete your own question :/

Comment: You're prohibited from voting to delete your own question if it has a positively scored answer or more than one answer.

Comment: @JonClements I know that. But then the order should be different. Right now they show a very scary warning, then when you decide take the risk then get a message you just cant delete anything.

Answer (score 15):

Lots.

There's no precise threshold—deletions contribute to a score that's weighed against your positive contributions to the site. So if *all you do here* is ask lousy questions, wait for them to get answered, and then delete them (and yes, there ***are*** people who do exactly that), you'll get banned pretty quickly.

On the other hand, if you spend lots of time writing useful questions and helpful answers (and it appears that you do), and *occasionally* find yourself needing to delete something… It won't matter at all; your positive contributions would greatly outweigh any negative contributions from the handful of deletions.

Comment: But I cant delete my question.

Comment: No, as there is a positive scored answer. This is to prevent wasting time from answerers.

Answer (score 3):

Your question cannot be answered *by design*. The details of the question/answer ban algorithm are deliberately not made public, so that it will be more difficult to game the system.

Basically, don't worry about it. You've asked a lot of questions, and many of them have been at least somewhat well received.